# setting field to blank after validation in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am new to JSF and going through one JSF application.

I want to validate one Password field for Blank string.

I know instead of doing it in Javascript, I am calling a function for validation.

My need is, if value of the password field is blank then it is validated from validator function till now it is going correctly but after validation when it come =s to UI bav=ck at that time password field should be empty.

If password field is empty(contains spaces only) then i want it to set it as blank or else keep data as it is.

My try till now,
JSF view page singin.xhtml

```
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputBox" style="margin: 3px;"
                        value="Password" />
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true" 
                        requiredMessage="Please enter your password"
                        value="#{userActionManager.dto.password}" 
                        validator="#{userActionManager.validateSamePassword}">

                            <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" bypassUpdates="true" />
                    </h:inputSecret>
```

Validator method.

```
    public void validateSamePassword(FacesContext fc, UIComponent component, Object obj) {
         System.out.println("UserActionManager.validateSamePassword()");

         String confirmPassword = (String)obj;
         System.out.println("Password is :" + confirmPassword);
            if(confirmPassword!=null && confirmPassword.trim().equals("")) {
              FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Password cannot be blank", " detail Passwords do not match!");

//            System.out.println(component.getFamily());
//            String field1Id = (String) component.getAttributes().get("password");

              // Find the actual JSF component for the client ID.
//            UIInput textInput = (UIInput) fc.getViewRoot().findComponent("password");
//            textInput.setValue("");

              dto.setPassword(null);

              throw new ValidatorException(message);
            }else{
                dto.setPassword(confirmPassword);
            }
    }
```

I tried option   dto.setPassword(null); but when it returns to view, blank spaces in password field is still there and i have to manually remove.

what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Within your validator, call `resetValue()` on the instance of `UIComponent` passed as argument

```
public void validateSamePassword(FacesContext fc, UIComponent component, Object obj) {
     System.out.println("UserActionManager.validateSamePassword()");

     String confirmPassword = (String)obj;
     System.out.println("Password is :" + confirmPassword);
        if(confirmPassword!=null && confirmPassword.trim().equals("")) {
          FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,   "Password cannot be blank", " detail Passwords do not match!");

          component.resetValue();

          throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }else{
            dto.setPassword(confirmPassword);
        }
}
```

`dto.setPassword(null)` will not affect the value in the password box as input components are designed to preserve the values that caused them to fail validation. `resetValue()` is a method that will cause the component to reset it's value to an uninitialized state

EDIT: The solution above resets the input value prematurely. Technically, validation doesn't fail until a `ValidationException` is thrown. To effectively reset the field:

1. Define a listener event that will reset the value of the component only after validation fails

   ```
   public void resetPwd(ComponentSystemEvent evt) throws IOException {
   HtmlInputSecret txt = (HtmlInputSecret) evt.getComponent();
   if(!txt.isValid()){ //make sure that the validation failed 
       txt.resetValue();
      }

   }
   ```
2. Attach the listener event to the `postValidate` event listener on the password component. This will ensure that the value is reset only after validation has failed.

   ```
     <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true" 
                   requiredMessage="Please enter your password"
                   value="#{userActionManager.dto.password}" 
                   validator="#{userActionManager.validateSamePassword}">
                       <f:event name="postValidate" listener="#{userActionManager.resetPwd}"/>
                       <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" bypassUpdates="true" />
               </h:inputSecret>
   ```

The key here is to reset the value at the right time. Other options for time include the `preRenderView` event and `postAddToView` event. It's all in the timing

Comment: component.resetValue(); there is no such method on UIComponent. I tried like ((UIInput)component).resetValue() and I found resetValue is there in UIInput. Still no success. blank value is still present in Field and I want to make it clear.

Comment: @JayeshPatel, actually that makes sense. My mistake. Technically, the validation doesn't fail until you throw `ValidationException`. The current solution I've proposed is prematurely resetting the value. See my update for a more appropriate timing.

Comment: `resetValue()` is not definied in `UIComponent`. It's definied in `EditableValueHolder` interface which is implemented by among others `UIInput`.

Answer (score 1):

If a component is marked invalid, then it won't redisplay the model value (in your case, the value from the `dto`). Instead, it will redisplay its [submitted value](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getSubmittedValue%28%29). You just need to set the submitted value to an empty string.

Replace

```
dto.setPassword(null);
```

by

```
((UIInput) component).setSubmittedValue("");
```